# covert onnx model into OpenVino

Tags: python, openvino

```
python mo --input_model number.onnx
```

run the above code in OpenVino model_optimizer cmd
I get the error ( The "number.onnx" is not existing file)

Comment: Can you try passing the full path to your model or change the command above to `./number.onnx` if your model is in the directory where you execute MO?

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is to give the full path of your model location.

```
python mo --input_model <INPUT_MODEL_PATH>\model.onnx
```

Refer to [Converting an ONNX model](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_MO_DG_prepare_model_convert_model_Convert_Model_From_ONNX.html).